# Erase element from std::list using a pointer?

Tags: c++, list, std

```
class SororityBeerExpo{
public:

     std::list<LaysCrankdPepChip> m_chipList;

     void destroyChip(LaysCrankdPepChip * target)
     {
         // m_chipList needs to erase that which is pointed at by target but
         // erase() requires an iterator which is not what we got to work with
         // remove() needs a value which is not right either
     }
}
```

My question, is how would one delete an element in a list, with a pointer that points to that element?  I would like to do this without using Iterators in place of pointers.

Comment: The only way possible AFAIK is linear search til you find the pointer. Just use iterators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a [linear] search for the element in the list, comparing the address of each element to your pointer ([`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) will fit the bill).  Of course, you will still be using an iterator in the end, because that's what [`list::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) needs.

Comment: You could use [remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) which would eliminate the call to `erase`.

Comment: @JesseGood: True.  But that will end up unnecessarily searching all of the elements, even if you find the match early on.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly (although see Benjamin's answer for an indirect way of doing it). A list node contains more data than just the object being contained (e.g. pointers to the previous and next nodes), but your raw pointer only points to the contained object.